# Why does getPort() for DatagramSocket return -1?

Tags: java, udp

I created a DatagramSocket and called getPort on it, and it always returned -1. In the javadocs, for the empty DatagramSocket constructor, it says that it will attach itself to an available port. I highly doubt my computer is using every port. At which point in the life cycle does it actually get a port number assigned to it?

Comment: please post a code snippet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DatagramSocket.getPort` [returns the port to which the socket is connected](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#getPort%28%29) - i.e. the port on the *other* end of the connection, if you've connected the socket.

Since you haven't connected the socket, it returns -1.

To get the port number at your end, use [`getLocalPort`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#getLocalPort%28%29) instead.